# ansible json_query is omitting desired key/values

Tags: json, ansible

For example, I have the following structure that ansible is pulling via an API url:

```
"records": [
  {
    "data0": "string",
    "data1": {
      "internal0": "string",
      "internal1": {
        "subthing0": "string",
        "subthing1": {
          "otherstuff": {
            "evenmore stuff": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

To filter the json and get the key/value I need I am using the following:

```
"{{ set_var.content | from_json | json_query('records[*].data1.internal1.subthing0') }}"
```

The debugger returns empty json, however if I use:

```
{{ set_var.content | from_json | json_query('records[*].data1.internal1') }}
```

I can see all of the key/values of subthing1 but subthing0 no longer shows up at all and the string of subthing0 is what is a needed variable to continue the next task. Why is subthing0 not returning at all unless I only query records?

Comment: Post the JSON `set_var.content`

Comment: set_var.content was the initial block of code.

Answer (score 0):

Given the initial block of code in *set_var.content* the expressions

```yaml
  result1: "{{ set_var.content|
               json_query('records[*].data1.internal1') }}"
  result2: "{{ set_var.content|
               json_query('records[*].data1.internal1.subthing0') }}"
```

give

```yaml
  result1:
  - subthing0: string
    subthing1:
      otherstuff:
        evenmore stuff: string
```

```yaml
  result2:
  - string
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    set_var:
      content: "{{ lookup('file', 'records.json') }}"
  
    result1: "{{ set_var.content|
                 json_query('records[*].data1.internal1') }}"
    result2: "{{ set_var.content|
                 json_query('records[*].data1.internal1.subthing0') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: set_var
    - debug:
        var: result1
    - debug:
        var: result2
```